# RSPEC Setup Help - Mountain Lion Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, macos, rspec

Setting up my first developing environment, so bear with me. Running Mountain Lion, Ruby 1.9.3, Gems 1.8.25 and RVM 1.19.1.

Trying to get RSPEC up and running, but I keep getting an error. I think it has to do with my PATH, as most questions about this refer to the fact that their shell (Bash?) is looking in the wrong place.

Using this wonderful tutorial: http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2007/05/14/an-introduction-to-rspec-part-i/

I've tried running the simplest rspec files and get an error, so I tried just typing "spec" (no quotes) in the command-line. That gives me the error "-bash: spec: command not found" (no quotes).

Looked around stackoverflow and saw that the command was updated to "rspec" instead of "spec"? So when I type "rspec" (no quotes) into the command line I get this nonsense:

```
Evans-MacBook-Pro:~ Evan$ rspec
/Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/Evan/spec (LoadError)
from /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
from /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
from /Users/Evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Regarding previous answers I found to this question: my attempts to alter the .bashrc just left me confused about what the heck I was doing, and I don't think I got the syntax right (also it didn't work).

Any thoughts? Much appreciated!

Evan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rspec assumes your specs in a `spec/` directory which cannot be found. Try running

```
rspec spec_tutorial
```

Btw. this tutorial is pretty outdated. Try using [rspec.info](http://rspec.info/) instead for example.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I ran the code you supplied and got the exact same error.

Comment: Did you create the `spec_tutorial` dir as described?

Comment: I typed "rspec spec_tutorial" (no quotes) in my command line and it gave me the error lines I pasted in my question.

Comment: You're right! That tutorial was way old. Found Code School's walkthough, and I guess my problem was that the pathing works differently now than it did when that tutorial was written. So I was basically diving way deeper than I needed to try and answer my question. All had to do with where and how I was saving my files. Oh well.